# How to set and use global array variable in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Here is my code for storing the words extracted from a log file into an array, which I want to use in the batch file later on.

```
cls
@echo off
set /a i=0
TIMEOUT 2
REM I want to save the words from newlog.txt into an array for later use in batch file.
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%G IN (newlog.txt) DO ( set a[%i%]=%%H 
& set /a i+=1 @echo !a[%i%]! )
@echo %i%
@echo a[%i%]
TIMEOUT 200
```

I just want to use them as global variables.

Comment: why are you stipulating three tokens when you're only using the second token?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
set /a i=0
REM I want to save the words from newlog.txt into an array for later use in batch file.
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%G IN (q48428047.txt) DO ( 
 set a[!i!]=%%H&set /a i+=1)

SET a[
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q48428047.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Note that `%i%` will be replaced by the value of `i` *as it was when the *`for`*was encountered* that is, `0`.

Your second `set` within your parentheses is incorrect. It's missing the `&` before the `@echo`. Also, you appear to be attempting to increment `i` and then show the corresponding array entry, which makes no sense because you haven't yet stored anything in that array-entry, you've attempted to install it in the previous position. It won't work anyway, because `%i%` will be replaced by `0`, not the varying value of `i`.

And whereas you may get the count-of-lines appearing on the screen, a[*numlines*] will not be defined.

Use `pause` to stop the batch for perusal. Preferably, run the command from the prompt, not by clicking.

The modified code reads each line of the file putting the first word in `%%G`, second in `%%H` and third in `%%I`. it then assigns `%%H` to a[*currentlinenumber*] and increments the line number in `i`.

The `set a[` will display all environment variables whose names start with `a[`.

Comment: omg , it worked , thank you !!!!!!!! sorry i had a lot of mistakes , and i'm not native English speak, thanks a million, this code will make me some money!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer already provided, if you really have a need to `Echo` each variable value immediately after it is `Set` then you would need to invoke a `Call` command:

```bat
@Echo Off

Rem Undefine any existing variables which begin with a[
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"(Set a[) 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="

Set "i=0"
ClS
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=2 Delims= " %%A In ("newlog.txt") Do (
    Set "a[!i!]=%%A"
    Call Echo "%%a[!i!]%%"
    Set /A i+=1
)
If %i% GEq 1 Echo(&Echo %i% variables were defined&Echo(
(Set a[) 2>Nul
Timeout 200
```